# find group element thrust then find average

Tags: vector, cuda, thrust

I have four vectors like this

```
d_xx[0]= 0.75   d_yy[0]= 0.75   d_vx[0]= 1.05488    d_vy[0]= 0.0427136
d_xx[1]= 0.25   d_yy[1]= 0.75   d_vx[1]= 2.03481    d_vy[1]= -0.757107
d_xx[2]= 0.75   d_yy[2]= 0.25   d_vx[2]= 0.234851   d_vy[2]= 1.63537
d_xx[3]= 0.25   d_yy[3]= 0.25   d_vx[3]= -0.442835  d_vy[3]= -0.00224912
d_xx[4]= 1.75   d_yy[4]= 0.75   d_vx[4]= 1.86096    d_vy[4]= -0.822878
d_xx[5]= 1.25   d_yy[5]= 0.75   d_vx[5]= -1.52816   d_vy[5]= -1.94596
...
```

How to find element in range of given between `xx_low = 0` , `xx_high = 1` and `yy_low = 0` , `yy_high = 1`, then I want to find the average of column `d_vx[N]` and `d_vy[N]` using thrust.

How is the best way to do this? And must I sort it first or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of at least 3 possible implementations:

1. `sort` elements, `find_if` the last element which satisfies range criteria, then `reduce`
2. `copy_if` all elements which satisfy the range criteria into a new vector, then, then `reduce`
3. `transform_reduce` with a custom functor which nullifies elements not falling into the desired range.

The following code implements the third idea:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/transform_reduce.h>
#include <thrust/tuple.h>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct nullify
{
  T xx_low;
  T xx_high;
  T yy_low;
  T yy_high;

  nullify(T xx_low, T xx_high, T yy_low, T yy_high) : xx_low(xx_low), xx_high(xx_high), yy_low(yy_low), yy_high(yy_high){}

  using result_type = thrust::tuple<T,T,std::size_t>;

  template <typename Tuple>
  __host__ __device__
  result_type operator()(const Tuple& t)
  {
    const T& xx = thrust::get<0>(t);
    const T& yy = thrust::get<1>(t);

    return (xx >= xx_low && xx <= xx_high && yy >= yy_low && yy <= yy_high) ? thrust::make_tuple(thrust::get<2>(t), thrust::get<3>(t), 1) : thrust::make_tuple(T(0),T(0),0);
  }
};

struct tuple_plus
{
    template <typename Tuple>
    __host__ __device__
    Tuple operator()(const Tuple& lhs, const Tuple& rhs)
    {
        return thrust::make_tuple(thrust::get<0>(lhs) + thrust::get<0>(rhs),
                                  thrust::get<1>(lhs) + thrust::get<1>(rhs),
                                  thrust::get<2>(lhs) + thrust::get<2>(rhs));
    }
};


int main()
{
    using T = float;
    thrust::device_vector<T> d_xx(6);
    thrust::device_vector<T> d_yy(6);
    thrust::device_vector<T> d_vx(6);
    thrust::device_vector<T> d_vy(6);
    d_xx[0]= 0.75; d_yy[0]= 0.75; d_vx[0]= 1.05488;   d_vy[0]= 0.0427136;
    d_xx[1]= 0.25; d_yy[1]= 0.75; d_vx[1]= 2.03481;   d_vy[1]= -0.757107;
    d_xx[2]= 0.75; d_yy[2]= 0.25; d_vx[2]= 0.234851;  d_vy[2]= 1.63537;
    d_xx[3]= 0.25; d_yy[3]= 0.25; d_vx[3]= -0.442835; d_vy[3]= -0.00224912;
    d_xx[4]= 1.75; d_yy[4]= 0.75; d_vx[4]= 1.86096;   d_vy[4]= -0.822878;
    d_xx[5]= 1.25; d_yy[5]= 0.75; d_vx[5]= -1.52816;  d_vy[5]= -1.94596;

    T xx_low  = 0;
    T xx_high = 1;
    T yy_low  = 0;
    T yy_high = 1; 

    auto zip_begin = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(d_xx.begin(), d_yy.begin(), d_vx.begin(), d_vy.begin()));
    auto zip_end = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(d_xx.end(), d_yy.end(), d_vx.end(), d_vy.end()));

    using Functor = nullify<T>;
    using ResultTuple = typename Functor::result_type;
    ResultTuple result = thrust::transform_reduce(zip_begin, zip_end, nullify<T>(xx_low, xx_high, yy_low, yy_high), thrust::make_tuple(T(0), T(0), 0), tuple_plus());

    T avg_d_vx = thrust::get<0>(result) / thrust::get<2>(result);
    T avg_d_vy = thrust::get<1>(result) / thrust::get<2>(result);
    std::cout << "avg_d_vx=" << avg_d_vx << " avg_d_vy=" << avg_d_vy << std::endl;
}
```

**output**:

```
avg_d_vx=0.720426 avg_d_vy=0.229682
```

Comment: are this code using boost c++ library or not? i have an error "error: "template" is not allowed" when compiling it

Comment: @AnnasNasrudin this code does not use boost, however it uses C++11 (which requires CUDA 7).

Comment: i have use command `nvcc --std=c++11 ave.cu -o ave`, but show that error  above. i am using Cuda compilation tools, release 7.5, V7.5.17, and g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1) 5.4.0 20160609 compiler.

Comment: @AnnasNasrudin I think `template <typename Tuple>` and `__host__ __device__` were in the wrong order, I corrected that in my answer

Comment: Sorry for the off-topic remark, but I'm glad you're still answering question on the `cuda` tag.